# Need to add the full path of where test was referenced from

Tags: powershell, text, powershell-3.0

So far I have a hash table with 2 values in it. Right now the code below, exports all the unique lines and gives me a count of how many times the line was referenced in 100's of xml files.  This is one part.

I now need to find out which subfolder had the xml file in it that has that unique line of referenced in the hash table.  Is this possible?

```
$ht = @{}
Get-ChildItem -recurse -Filter *.xml | Get-Content | %{$ht[$_] = $ht[$_]+1}
$ht

# To export to CSV:
$ht.GetEnumerator() | select key, value | Export-Csv D:\output.csv
```

Comment: You only want the location of lines that had a count of 1?

Comment: Actually the ones with more than one

Comment: So instead of a count, you want to accumulate a list of file paths?

Comment: I would like to be able to export the count and the location of the xml, so I can find it later for further investigation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get file path to your output, you need to assign it to a variable in the first pipe.

Is this something similar to what you need?

```
$ht = @{}
Get-ChildItem -recurse -Filter *.xml | %{$path = $_.FullName; Get-Content $path} | % { $ht[$_] = $ht[$_] + $path + ";"}
```

The code above will return a hash-table in "config line" = "count" format.

**EDIT:**

If you need to return three elements (unique line, count and array of paths where it was found) it gets more complicated. Here is a code that will return an array of PSObjects. Each contains info for one unique line in XML files.

```
$ht = @()
$files = Get-ChildItem -recurse -Filter *.xml
foreach ($file in $files) {
    $path = $file.FullName
    $lines = Get-Content $path
    foreach ($line in $lines) {
        if ($match = $ht | where {$_.line -EQ $line}) {
            $match.count = $match.count + 1
            $match.Paths += $path
        } else {
            $ht += new-object PSObject -Property @{
                Count = 1
                Paths = @(,$path)
                Line = $line }
        }
    }
}

$ht
```

I'm sure it can be shortened and optimized, but hopefully it is enough to get you started.

Comment: Jan.. thanks for the response.  When I run your code, I get this error.

Comment: Cannot convert value "G:\GPO 
Backup\{00A82A8A-E303-4241-9C59-49DE137EBA07}\gpreport.xml" to type 
"System.Int32". Error: "Input string was not in a correct format."
At line:1 char:88
+ ... t $path} | % { $ht[$_] = $ht[$_] + $path + ";"}

Comment: You would get that error if you defined $ht as an array `$ht = @()`. In your question it was defined as a hashtable `$ht=@{}`.

Comment: Based on your comments on the question you are wanting to return, unique line, count, and all the paths where it was found. This is probably not going to be a "one liner". I will edit my answer when I'm at a PC.

Comment: Thank you for all your time.

Comment: if needed to export this to a csv file, how would I do it?  I tried `$ht.GetEnumerator() | select Count, Path, Line | Export-Csv c:\NLG_GPO_Sort.csv` but the Path portion is blank.  Please help.